# I cant make a .theme folder or .icon folder in nautilus

Tags: icons, themes

For some reason, I can't make a ".theme" or ".icon" file in the Ubuntu file browser to change my theme, or for some reason they are not shown.  When I try to make another one it always tells me that there is already a file called ".icon" or ".theme" but if I search for them in the search bar they are not shown.
My Linux version is Ubuntu 18.04 and I am running it on a Lenovo t420s with a i5 2400.. something.
Please Help.

Comment: ctrl + h to see hidden files and folders... files and folders that start with `. ` in ubuntu are hidden

Comment: Also, are you trying to create a folder or file since you've mentioned file in question body?

Answer (score 4):

The files and folders with a `.`(dot) before their names are hidden by default to see them you can:

1. Run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, or
2. Change the settings in nautilus to see them always.:

   [image]

You then run `cd ~/.icon` to change into that location and add what ever files you want to.

Answer (score 3):

By default, hidden files are not shown.
To enable this option, open the file manager, and click on the 3 horizontal bars then check the option 'show hidden files'.

[image]